# SQL sum displaying column as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert column into rows with its sum.

**Source Table:**

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name | TypeA | TypeB | TypeC |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| A    |    10 |     3 |    53 |
| B    |    25 |   543 |     5 |
| B    |    30 |     5 |     5 |
| B    |    21 |     3 |     5 |
| C    |    23 |     2 |   278 |
| C    |     0 |     3 |     7 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Required Result:**

```
+-------+----------+
| Type  | SumTotal |
+-------+----------+
| TypeA |      109 |
| TypeB |      559 |
| TypeC |      353 |
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to unpivot the data and then aggregate.  I recommend using `APPLY` and then `GROUP BY`:

```
select v.type, sum(v.val)
from t cross apply
     (values ('TypeA', TypeA), ('TypeB', TypeB), ('TypeC', TypeC)
     ) v(type, val)
group by v.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT to change column into row as follows

```
SELECT TypeValue, SumTotal
FROM (select sum(TypeA) as TypeA, Sum(TypeB) as TypeB, Sum(TypeC) as TypeC from YourTable) AS t
UNPIVOT
(
  SumTotal
  FOR TypeValue IN([TypeA], [TypeB], [TypeC])
) AS u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly UNPIVOT and Gordon's approach would be more performant, but if you have a variable or numerous columns, here is an technique that will dynamically unpivot your data without actually using dynamic sql.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(50),[TypeA] int,[TypeB] int,[TypeC] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A',10,3,53)
,('B',25,543,5)
,('B',30,5,5)
,('B',21,3,5)
,('C',23,2,278)
,('C',0,3,7)

Select C.Item
      ,Value = sum(C.value)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','int')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Name','Other','ColumnsToExclude')
             ) C
 Group By C.Item
```

**Returns**

```
Item    Value
TypeA   109
TypeB   559
TypeC   353
```